Characterization of the dual of intersection of Banach spaces.
Let $U,V$ Banach spaces and define $X = U\cap Y$ endowed with the norm $\|u\|_X = \|u\|_U + \|u\|_V$. If we take $\varphi \in U'$ and $\psi \in V'$, I can prove that $\varphi|_X + \psi|_X \in X'$, because for $u \in X$,
$$
|(\varphi|_X + \psi|_X)(u)| \leq  |\varphi(u)| + |\psi(u)| \leq C_1 \|u\|_U + C_2 \|u\|_V \leq (C_1 + C_2) \|u\|_X.
$$
Now take $f \in X'$. Is it true that $f = \varphi|_U + \psi_V$ for some $\varphi \in U'$ and $\psi \in V'$? I'm not sure if this makes sense. What should be the dual of $X$?
My problem: Consider $X = H^1(\mathbb{R}^N) \cap D^{1,q}(\mathbb{R}^N)$ endowed with the norm $\|u\|_X = \|u\|_{H^1(\mathbb{R}^N)} + \|u\|_{D^{1,q}(\mathbb{R}^N)}$. Now take $u_n, u \in X$ such that $u_n \rightharpoonup u$ in $H^1(\mathbb{R}^N)$ and $u_n \rightharpoonup u$ in $D^{1,q}(\mathbb{R}^N)$. I trying to prove that $u_n \rightharpoonup u$ in $X$. If what I asked is true, I would know how to prove it.
Edit: This question arose when I tried to prove that $X = H^1(\mathbb{R}^N) \cap D^{1,q}(\mathbb{R}^N)$ is reflexive. If anyone knows another approach to prove it I would be very
grateful.
In the following I write a idea I had, which I don't know whether is correct:
My attempt: Let $Y = C^\infty_0(\mathbb{R}^N)$ and $\phi \in X'$. Notice that $\phi|_Y$ is continuous from $Y$ to $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual norms from $H^1(\mathbb{R}^N)$ and $D^{1,q}(\mathbb{R}^N)$, respectively(I think I know how to prove it by showing the norms are equivalent just in $Y$). Denote by $f$ and $g$ the respective continuous extensions of $\phi$ to $H^1(\mathbb{R}^N)$ and $D^{1,q}(\mathbb{R}^N)$(using the Hahn Banach theorem). Observe that $(f|_X + g|_X)/2 \in X'$ and $(f|X + g|X)/2 = \phi$, because  $(f|X + g|X)/2(u) = \phi(u)$, for all  $u \in Y$ and  there is just one continuous extension of $Y$ to $X$, because $\overline{Y}^{\|\cdot\|_X} = X$.

Maybe I am missing something but can't you embed $X$ isometrically to a closed subspace of $U\times V$ where the latter is reflexive? Btw what is $D^{1,q}(\mathbb R^N)$?

$D^{1,q}(\mathbb{R}^N) = { u \in L^{q^}(\mathbb{R}^N) \text{ ; } |\nabla u| \in L^q(\mathbb{R}^N) }$, where $q^ = Nq/(N-q)$.
